# Can't post to my Wordpress site

Tags: errors, posting

Today's date is January 18, 2020. I am currently running WordPress version 5.3.2.  I am **NOT** a WordPress expert by any means.  So replies should take that under consideration.

My blog was working fine yesterday.  Today I am not able to post any new posts.  I made no changes to my site between yesterday (Jan 17, 2020) and today (Jan 18, 2020).

When I enter the posting editor the following message is displayed right below Permalink: ?preview=true:

> "You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."

[image]

I am not currently editing *any* page.

I installed the Fix Another Update in Progress plugin and ran it.  It said "There is no Update lock issue. Continue with your WordPress Update".

I searched the wp_options database file for core_updater.lock and found nothing.

One user answered a similar question by saying the database was full.  My provider, Ionos, doesn't restrict my database size as far as I know.

I replaced all of the Wordpress files with the exception of the wp-content folder.

I've basically tried everything I found online about this problem.

I am desperate to post to my blog again.  I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you check the value for Settings, Reading, 'Your homepage displays', 'A static page', 'Posts page' ? I'd guess you have a bad / empty value there. And/or delete the posts_page entry from wp_options in your database.

Comment: However that's not the new Gutenberg editor: are you using a plugin to disable Gutenberg? Any chance that's causing this?

Comment: FWIW -- You are not alone.  I am having exactly the same problem and would love some help here. Started on Saturday, just like you.

Comment: @Rup -- Gutenberg was updated on Saturday.  It was immediately after that this problem started.  I have tried to eliminate every vestige of Gutenberg through my dashboard.